# iPhone 4 width CSS

Tags: html, iphone, css

I'm developing a mobile version of my website. I have this code, tested on Galaxy S3, there is no scroll and the site displays okay.

```
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (max-width: 400px)" href="css/mobile.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (min-width: 401px)" href="css/desktop.css" /> 
</head>
```

On the iPhone 4 however, I get this. The image is a bit too large, and the top bar does not extend to the phone's full width. I assume that this is because iPhone's width is 480px, but how can I target the device and its width, ideally without creating another CSS file for it?

The top bar is set here, as border-top:

```
body { background-color:#F5F5F5; width: 100%; font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size:14px; margin: 0px auto; border-top: 15px solid #003663; line-height: 14px; }
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can go in your primary stylesheet:

```
/*Target iPhone's screen width*/
@media screen and (max-device-width: 480px){
/*Do not set fixed widths, use %*/
    body{
        -webkit-text-size-adjust:none;
        font-family:Helvetica, Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
        padding:5px;
    }
/*Set widths to 100%*/
    div{
        clear:both!important;
        display:block!important;
        width:100%!important;
        float:none!important;
        margin:0!important;
        padding:0!important;
    }
/*Create vertical navigation menu*/
    #nav,#nav li{
        float:none!important;
        clear:both!important;
        margin:0 0 20px 0!important;
        display:block;
        padding:0;
        text-align:left!important;
        width:100%;
    }
    #nav{
        border:1px solid #ccc;
        padding:5px;
        border-radius:5px;
    }
    #nav li{
        margin:0!important;
    }
    #nav li a{
        display:block;
    }
}
```